# Dismiss Bootstrap Modal with ng-if

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal, dismiss, angular-ng-if

I am using Bootstrap Modal in my angular application. I have a text area and upon click, the modal opens. See code below.

```
<textarea class="form-control" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="msg" 
type="text" class="form-control" name="msg"></textarea></form>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
...
```

I have a variable "node1" that is set to false. when this variable is true, I want the modal to close. I have tried

```
<span ng-if='node1' data-dismiss="modal"></span>
```

but it does not work. The modal only closes if i use data-dismiss on a button. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When do you want to hide or dismiss the modal? I mean on what action?

Comment: A follow up on @CrazyMac's comment, what action is setting `node1` to true?

Comment: @CrazyMac I am using angular-tree-control, when a node is selected I want the modal to close   <treecontrol class="tree-light"
   tree-model="dataTree"
   options="treeOptions"
   selected-node="node1"
</treecontrol>

Answer (score 1):

You can watch the node1 variable and then close modal if its value change to true

```
$scope.$watch('node1', function() {
    if(node1){
        //close the modal here
    }
});
```